# width of popup in html

Tags: html, css

I am following [this](https://www.codewithrandom.com/2023/03/01/popup-box-with-html-css/?expand_article=1) article

For me the text in the popup is a span which has multiple lines (`<br>`).

How can I make the width of the popup enough to adjust to the longest line and have vertical scrollbar in case the no of lines is more. Default it should be able to support 20 lines.

currently its showing like this:

[image]

And the content is:

```
BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843<br>Profile=IPSEC, Packet=IMIX, Mbps=884.6, KPPS=313.12, % Line Rate=4.67, % QFP=40.0<br>Profile=IPSEC, Packet=IMIX, Mbps=884.13, KPPS=313.12, % Line Rate=4.67, % QFP=40.0<br>Profile=IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_SNAT_ZBFW, Packet=IMIX, Mbps=884.67, KPPS=313.12, % Line Rate=4.67, % QFP=40.0<br>
```

style:

```
.modal-wrapper{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.508);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;

}
.modal{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 200%;
    background: wheat;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 35vh auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.modal a{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: crimson;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.modal-close{
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

my popup div:

```
 <div class="modal-wrapper">
     <div class="modal">
         <div class="modal-close">X</div>
         <div class="modal-content">
             <span>Results:</span>
             <br>
             <p style="font-size:70%;color:blue;" align="left" id="popup_content"></p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you add a [mre]?

Comment: Just FYI modals are [now part of CSS](https://youtu.be/RO40Opyizeg) which makes life a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the width of the pop up modal to max-content. [Max-content](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-min-content-max-content-fit-content-css/) will use as much space as it needs without wrapping. Set the `max-width` to `100vw` and `box-sizing: border box` to stop the whole thing overflowing.

For the height, I've used CSS custom properties to work out the number of lines to scroll and set `max-height` accordingly then set `overflow-y:auto`.

Marked up code below:

```css
.modal-wrapper {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.508);
  position: fixed;
  inset:0;
  /*top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;*/
  /*display: none;*/
}

.modal {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* added this */
  max-width: 100vw;  /* changed this from 300px */  
  width: max-content; /* changed this */
  background: wheat;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 35vh auto;
  /*width: 200%;*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.modal a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: crimson;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.modal-close {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-content p {
  --max-lines: 5;
  --font-size: 0.7rem;
  --line-height: 1.2;
  max-height: calc(var(--max-lines) * var(--font-size) * var(--line-height));
  overflow-y:auto;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  line-height: var(--line-height);
  color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-close">X</div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span>Results:</span>
      <br>
      <p id="popup_content">
    BLD_V179_THROTTLE_LATEST_20230513_170843<br>Profile=IPSEC, Packet=IMIX, Mbps=884.6, KPPS=313.12, % Line Rate=4.67, % QFP=40.0<br>Profile=IPSEC, Packet=IMIX, Mbps=884.13, KPPS=313.12, % Line Rate=4.67, % QFP=40.0<br>Profile=IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_SNAT_ZBFW,
        Packet=IMIX, Mbps=884.67, KPPS=313.12, % Line Rate=4.67, % QFP=40.0<br>xx</br>
    xx</br>xx</br>xx</br>xx</br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like magic !